# Powershell Script to delete files recursively in every folder except 10 with the most recent write time

Tags: windows, powershell, skip

I would like to write a script as in a title. I have been getting trouble with doing it recursively, so i tried just passing path in argument. The problem is, when i pass 1 argument to the script it works properly, but when I start passing more, it doesn't skip 10 files in next folders, it skips the right amount of files only in the first folder. If anyone can help doing it recursively and passing only path to the parent directory or just passing every path separately, I would be pleased. Here is my code, it works properly only with the first passed argument.

```
Param(
    [string[]]$path
    )



Get-ChildItem $path |

    #skip directories
    Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } |
    
    #Sort by last write time
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | 
    
    #Skip 10 most recent
    Select-Object -Skip 10 |
    
    Remove-Item -whatif
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the entire array to Get-ChildItem, it will pipe all files in all the directories to be sorted att once. Try wrapping your entire pipe in a foreach.

```
foreach($item in $path){
  Get-ChildItem $item | 
     Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } | 
     Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | 
     Select-Object -Skip 10 | Remove-Item -whatif
}
```